# Magic square cannot hide

Tags: html, css, wordpress, hide

I have my page - *link*
And at the bottom of It when loading page showing dark grey square which I don't know how to hide. Tried with inspect element, but no results.. Maybe you can do something?

Comment: Don't see any grey square in Chrome. It's probably because you have your `body` background colour set to `#666`, try setting it to `#fff`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try to change background-color of body to #FFF

```
body{ background-color:#FFF; }
```